# Conexión dinámica a BD con JPA

Tags: java, jpa, firebird

Estoy trabajando con Firebird mas JPA y SpringData para el manejo de las conexiones a bases de datos Firebird.
Tengo configuradas las conexiones en mi applicationContext.xml y todo me funciona de maravilla. Ahora me surge la necesidad de conectarme a otras bases de datos, cuya localización no conozco de antemano. 
No se como enfocar el problema. ¿Alguna pista?

Comment: Hola Pepe! Bienvenido. [Pista1](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) [Pista2](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algo así podría valer, pero no has aportado información suficiente como para saberlo a ciencia cierta.
Crea un persistence-unit sin propiedades de BD:

```
  <persistence>
      <persistence-unit name="miPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
          <class>stack.overflow.Respuesta</class>
      </persistence-unit>
  </persistence>
```

Donde necesites crear un entityManager:

```
       //Inicialización factoría
        EntityManagerFactory emf;
        Map properties = new HashMap();
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");//Clase del driver a utilizar
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/miBD");//URL de conexión a la BD
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.username", "root");//Usuario
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.password", "mysql");//Contraseña
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");//Dialecto hibernate
        properties.put("hibernate.show-sql", "true");
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("miPersistenceUnit",properties);

        //Creación EntityManager
        EntityManager entityManager = (EntityManager) emf.createEntityManager();

        //Insert ejemplo
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        Respuesta miRespuesta = new Respuesta(1,"A ver si vale");
        entityManager.persist(miRespuesta);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: Creo que si, que me he pasado de lacónico. Aún así la solución propuesta por ti me ha funcionado perfectamente, así que solo me queda que agradecerte la ayuda. ¡Gracias!